# podman , cannot set user namespace

Tags: podman

while running
`podman run hello-world`

i am getting below issue

**

- cannot set user namespace.

**

Earlier there was some mount issue as below:

"/" is not a shared mount, this could cause issues or missing mounts with rootless containers

someone suggested that this could be due to private mount as below:

```
PROPAGATION
private
```

so to resolve this

i executed `sudo mount --make-rshared /`

which solved the private mount to shared

```
findmnt -o PROPAGATION /
PROPAGATION
shared
```

but now i started getting  cannot set user namespace while running
`podman run hello-world`

Comment: Hi user5635636, why is the 'Kubernetes' tag here? I think your question is not related to Kubernetes. What OS are you running podman on? There are no issues running `podman run hello-world` on `linux`.

Comment: Kubernetes tag was here for better reach because anyone who is using podman must also be working with kubernetes somehow, so if anyone have faced similar issue can guide. OS is ubuntu.

Comment: I tried this command on Ubuntu 20.04 and had no problems at all. What is your Ubuntu version? How did you install the podman?

Comment: sudo podman run hello-world, is running , but do not know why its not running as rootless

Comment: ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: podman was running fine before and podman was installed by "sudo apt-get -qq -y install podman", however i had done some wsl integration with visual studio, thereafter, it stopped working as rootless

Comment: man, you should always point out that you are using ubuntu 20.04 in **wsl2**. It is a different thing than normal Ubuntu :)  And it's good that you clarified that it worked before.

Comment: :) running by root is working but running rootless is same problem

Comment: @user5635636 is there anyway for us to run that command before we run the wsl distro itself? So we don't need manually to run each time?

Comment: Why is docker tagged here? Have you gone through the steps to uninstall podman and install docker? If so, please show your work.

Comment: Running the same command just once again helped in my case  Seems the first error triggered some automatic fixing.

Answer (score -3):

Add /tmp to /etc/fstab

`echo "none  /tmp  tmpfs  defaults  0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`

Tested this with WSL2 on Windows 11 with Ubuntu 22

Comment: Can you explain why this works or why this is needed?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on WSL2 on Windows 10 with Ubuntu 22.04